# Converting Sybase ASE-specific *= and =* into LEFT/RIGHT OUTER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sap-ase

I have some PHP applications running on Sybase ASE 15.0.2, and I need to port them to MicroSoft SQL Server 2008 R2.
Many of the queries use the Sybase-only syntax with `*= and =*`
Is there an automatic way to convert a query from the Sybase syntax to the standard syntax using LEFT/RIGHT OUTER JOIN ?

Comment: Please refer to [this](http://mssql-mysql.blogspot.in/) link to help you:

Comment: I really mean automatic. I know how to do it manually, but the queries are many and complex.

Answer (score 3):

`*=` indicates a left outer join

`=*` indicates a right outer join

so

```
select * 
from tableA, titleauthor
where tableA.ID *= titleauthor.ID
```

means

```
select * 
from tableA left join titleauthor
on tableA.ID = titleauthor.ID
```

I dont think you will find a tool to do it automatically for you. Even though is simple, it can get tricky and an automated process wouldnt be 100% reliable (I think)

Answer (score 0):

For future conversion issues experienced by others (we're going from SAP ASE 16.0 to SQL Server 2016) simply select the query in SSMS, execute CTRL+SHIFT+Q to open the query designer. This will convert to SQL Server ANSI standard where possible.